# shellscript: add (upcounting) number value between matching strings

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have more than 100 files with with over 9000 lines of text. A preview extract of one of the files looks like this:

```
<productname>kidscar1</productname>
<productid>98</productid>
<productname>kidscar2</productname>
<productcolor>yellow</productcolor>
<productid>101</productid>
<productname>kidscar3</productname>
<productsize>xxl</productsize>
<productcolor>green</productcolor>
<productid>104</productid>
<productname>kidscar4</productname>
<productcolor>bleu</productcolor>
<productsize>xl</productsize>
<producttype>electric</producttype>
<productid>103</productid>
```

I'm trying to change (re-arange) the product ID's starting from a different product ID and automatically count this up for the next lines containing an product ID.

I was thinking of a shell script solution which I could use in a for loop.

```
**sh idscript.sh oldfile.txt 1000 productid > newfile.txt**
```

Result:

```
<productname>kidscar1</productname>
<productid>1000</productid>
<productname>kidscar2</productname>
<productcolor>yellow</productcolor>
<productid>1001</productid>
<productname>kidscar3</productname>
<productsize>xxl</productsize>
<productcolor>green</productcolor>
<productid>1002</productid>
<productname>kidscar4</productname>
<productcolor>bleu</productcolor>
<productsize>xl</productsize>
<producttype>electric</producttype>
<productid>1003</productid>`
```

I know that it's possible to replace a whole line in sed with the next command:

```
**sed "s/<productid>100</productid>=.*/<productid>=<productid>1000</productid>/g"**
```

But how can I make this work to get the above result? If there are other (simpler) ways to achieve this, i like to hear it also!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sed is for s/old/new that is all. In this case you need a numeric variable to keep track of the incrementing product and sed doesn't support variables at all so just use awk:

```
$ awk -v pid=1000 '/<productid>/{sub(/[0-9]+/,pid++)}1' file
<productname>kidscar1</productname>
<productid>1000</productid>
<productname>kidscar2</productname>
<productcolor>yellow</productcolor>
<productid>1001</productid>
<productname>kidscar3</productname>
<productsize>xxl</productsize>
<productcolor>green</productcolor>
<productid>1002</productid>
<productname>kidscar4</productname>
<productcolor>bleu</productcolor>
<productsize>xl</productsize>
<producttype>electric</producttype>
<productid>1003</productid>
```

Comment: Nice. productid string is used as RS and removing all numbers and writing the incremented pid startig from 1000?

Comment: No, `pid` is a variable containing a number and I'm just replacing the existing number with its value and post-incrementing it. I'm not doing anything with RS.

Comment: Thanx for the infor Ed, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Following `awk` may also help you on same too.

```
awk -v val=1000 '/productid/{sub(/>[0-9]+</,">"val++"<")} 1'  Input_file
```

Comment: @EdMorton, done the change sir, yes I thought if in case null value there for `<productid></productid>`, though OP didn't mention it but thought to cover it in it, thanks for letting me know.